# load and show images from dog and cat dataset with keras and python

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

how can i return and display images from dataset using keras and python,

this is my code to download and unzip the dataset

```
_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs_filterted', origin=_URL, extract=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

train_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'validation')
train_dir = pathlib.Path(train_dir)
train_dir
```

the result is this path:

```
PosixPath('/root/.keras/datasets/cats_and_dogs_filterted/train')
```

now if I try this code:

```
cats = list(train_dir.glob('cats/*'))
cats
```

just return null list []

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the issue in colab. A workaround is to set the `cache_subdir`, which is  an absolute path, and the file will be saved at that location.

```
# Set "cache_subdir" to path-to-folder
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs_filterted', cache_subdir='/content/cats_and_dogs_filterted', origin=_URL, extract=True)
```

To list all the files of a specific folder you can do it like below

```
cats = glob.glob('/content/cats_and_dogs_filterted/cats_and_dogs_filtered/train/cats/*')
```

Please refer to this [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/7d7719ee7fdcb100dd5ab59eb2a31a0a/73293342.ipynb) to check the output. Thank you!